# IHttpHandler: Speeding up performance with parallelism?

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading

I have a IHttpHandler which executes three methods:

- a = Method_A
- b = Method_B
- c = Method_C(a,b)

The computation of method A and method B is completely independent. Method C uses the results of method A and B. Currently the methods are executed sequently. To get a better overall performance of the IHttpHandler, my idea is to compute method A and B parallel. Method C should be started if A and B have finished. Is this possible and how?

Regards, Thorsten

Answer (score 3):

Sure it is possible; the real fun, though, is figuring out if it is sensible. If the work is CPU-bound, then *for a low number of requests* it'll scale (it'll look good on a local machine with just you, for example) - however, if there are lots of other parallel requests, then you could actually *degrade* performance (threading has overhead, and you have finite cores).

If you have low request numbers (i.e. you have enough cores to handle the load in parallel without running out), or if the work is primarily IO-bound you should be OK, though.

Simply start a Task for one of the items:

```
var task = new Task<ResultType>(() => Method_B());
task.Start();
var a = Method_A();
var b = task.Result;
Method_C(a, b);
```

Note that this does introduce a number of related issues - for example, the code in `Method_B()` will not have direct access to any of the request-related context. Ideally, gather all the information `Method_B()` will need *first* (on the main http-request thread), and pass that in via a simple data-type, unrelated to the http-context. Likewise, anything that uses thread-local data (`TransactionScope` for example) will not flow automatically into `Method_B()`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use TPL (Task parallel library). Check out at this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Iti s possible and trivial - either with async extensions or just queueing work items and using signals to synchronize the return being available.

The main questin is whether it makes sense. It only makes sense when the server is not busy calculating anyway. Because if it is - you cna not magically craete new cpu cores.